# Figures names in Pandas Boxplots

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I created 2 boxplots using pandas. 
Then each figure gets referenced with `plt.gcf()`

When trying to show the plots, only the last boxplot gets shown. Its like fig1 is getting overwritten. 
What is the correct way of showing both boxplots?

This is the sample code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates   = pd.date_range('20000101', periods=10)
df      = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
df['A'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10))  
df['B'] = np.random.randint(-1,2,size=10)
df['C'] = range(1,11)
df['D'] = range(12,22)

# first figure
ax_boxplt1 = df[['A','B']].boxplot()
fig1 = plt.gcf()


# second figure
ax_boxplt2  = df[['C','D']].boxplot()
fig2    = plt.gcf()

# print figures
figures = [fig1,fig2]
for fig in figures:
    print(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a figure with two axes and plot to each of them separately

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2)

dates   = pd.date_range('20000101', periods=10)
df      = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
df['A'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10))  
df['B'] = np.random.randint(-1,2,size=10)
df['C'] = range(1,11)
df['D'] = range(12,22)

# first figure
df[['A','B']].boxplot(ax=axes[0])  # Added `ax` parameter

# second figure
df[['C','D']].boxplot(ax=axes[1])  # Added `ax` parameter

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to get two figures, define the figure before plotting to it. You can use a number enumerate the figures.

```
plt.figure(1)
# do something with the first figure

plt.figure(2)
# do something with the second figure
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates   = pd.date_range('20000101', periods=10)
df      = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
df['A'] = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10))  
df['B'] = np.random.randint(-1,2,size=10)
df['C'] = range(1,11)
df['D'] = range(12,22)

# first figure
fig1=plt.figure(1)
ax_boxplt1 = df[['A','B']].boxplot()

# second figure
fig2=plt.figure(2)
ax_boxplt2  = df[['C','D']].boxplot()

plt.show()
```

[image]